Integrate Google DialogFlow with Whatsapp business number without 3rd Party
I want to integrate Google DialogFlow with WhatsApp Business number in my application without using any paid 3rd party API. I searched many platforms like Twilio, AiSensy,
Kommunicate and many more but all are paid services.
Please suggest any idea which fullfill my requirement.
Thanks
I tried AiSensy but it is paid.
